# How to take advantage of the freeness of ethereum testnet and do simple ERC20 transfers on the mainnet when needed?

Tags: solidity, mainnet, goerli

This is a very broad question.
Currently we have our product running on the goerli testnet, it works fine and the clients are happy because it is fast and free. But our V2.0 takes into consideration a real ERC20. So, two times within the user flow we need to transfer the token between two parties. The rest of the logic remains the same as on the testnet.

What we would like to achieve is to keep the the entire logic on the testnet, because it is cheap and makes the current customers happy. But within our functions on the testnet do specific calls for those transfers on the mainnet.

1. is it possible to do so? I guess not.
2. Any other idea on taking advantage of the blockchain technology for the business logic (for a very cheap cost) and to do specific calls for the transfers of the token to the mainnet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to combine data from testnets and the mainnet in any meaningfully decentralized way. Furthermore, testnets may be reset at any time and weird stuff may happen there - they are not meant for production use. They are called *test* nets for a reason - newest stuff is tried there and sometimes it fails. So you can use it, but at your own risk.

If you want cheaper transaction, but the security of the Ethereum mainnet, you should look into Layer 2 solutions, such as Optimism. Or then choose a completely different EVM-based blockchain, which has lower gas costs.